# How to work a B-Tree index for a column with low cardinality

Tags: indexing, bitmap, b-tree

The BITMAP index is recommended when the column has less than 100 options, and let's assume I have a varchar column, and that column can store more than 100 options.

Okay, we should create a B-Tree index for this column, but how would the B-Tree index be executed?

For example, here's how a B-Tree index on a column that does NOT have Low Cardinality executes:

[image: index b-tree]

And here we have how the index BITMAP on a column that HAS Low Cardinality is executed:

[image: index bitmap]

My question is: How is the index B-Tree on a column that HAS Low Cardinality executed?

Comment: A b-tree index for a column with low cardinality should execute the same way as any other. Perhaps there's some key detail missing in your question?

Comment: @boneill I thought the b-tree search only looked for one element... but you're right, it will work just the same.